# Best way to handle switching ViewControllers with Rotation, iOS

Tags: ios, rotation, orientation

My current view is portrait, displaying a particular design. When I rotate it landscape wise, I want to switch to a new design, and in particular a new ViewController, with new .h/.m files.

Should I be approaching it this way? Can someone point me in the right direction?
Can a rotation trigger a segue?

Answer (score 0):

```
-(void) willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration {
if (toInterfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft) {
    NSLog(@"Landscape left");
   //Present or dismiss your new view controller accordingly 
} else if (toInterfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight) {
    NSLog(@"Landscape right");
    //Present or dismiss your new view controller accordingly 
} else if (toInterfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait) {
    NSLog(@"Portrait");
   //Present or dismiss your new view controller accordingly  
} else if (toInterfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown) {
    NSLog(@"Upside down");
   //Present or dismiss your new view controller accordingly  
}
}
```